# PHP strtotime ASP equivalent

Tags: php, asp-classic, strtotime

Hey for any PHP programmers out there in need of a way to get strtotime using ASP.  I couldn't find a simple function in native ASP so I wrote the following.  Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%

Function formatNumber(value, digits) 
if digits > len(value) then 
formatNumber = String(digits-len(value),"0") & value 
else 
formatNumber = value 
end if 
End Function


date1 = "1970/01/01 00:00:00"
date2 = "2013/11/12 10:00:00"
strtotime = DateDiff("s",date1,date2)
strtotime = thestr-3600
Response.write(strtotime) 'number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT

%>
```